# Is it possible sync only iPad-optimized apps to my iPad?

Tags: applications, ipad, itunes, data-synchronization

It is tedious to manually pick iPad-optimized apps from all the apps in iTunes when syncing with iPad. I just want

- *iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad Apps* - apps designed for both iPhone and iPad, and
- *iPad Apps* - apps designed for iPad only

on my iPad, but not

- *iPhone and iPod touch Apps* - apps designed for iPhone only.

Comment: @an0 I've tried to clarify the question so it reads like I think you intended, please feel free to edit the question further if I've misunderstood your intent.

Comment: Good question. It's annoying to have new iPhone-only apps I've purchased appear in iPad too.

Comment: I too am amazed that Apple hasn't made a deeper way to do this: a checkbox that tells iTunes that you want only iPad and Universal apps on the iPad, no apps that aren't built for the bigger screen.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Apps tab in iTunes (when your iPad is plugged in), you should be able to sort your applications by type, using the dropdown box above the list of apps. I believe you can then move down the list with your arrow keys and press the spacebar to check/uncheck the ones you don't want. It's not quite automatic, but I think this may be the fastest way to do it.

(I can't verify 100% the key presses here; I'm on a machine right now that doesn't have iTunes installed.)

Answer (score 0):

Go into iTunes click on "apps" and under the category "iPhone and iPod touch apps" - delete them all.

Now that answer was way too simple so I am assuming you also have an iphone so you want the apps to remain in your store?

If so - after jailbreaking your ipad there is a cydia crack that changes the display icons of non-ipad apps to have a black border. Not ideal but these can easily be distinguished on the ipad to delete when in moving/deleting app mode.